# Get indexPath of Core Data object in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsindexpath

I have a UITableView that I'm populating from Core Data with the following NSfetchedResultsController:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

I have another method attached to an "Add" button that adds a new Core Data item to database.  As soon as the object is added, my table updates properly and the new object is shown in its correct spot according to the "date" sort in the fetched results controller.  My new object is added using today's date for its "date" attribute.  I add the object like this:

```
NSManagedObject *newEvent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newEvent setValue:@"New Client" forKey:@"name"];
[newEvent setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];
NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Core Data error!  Could not save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Now, as part of my "Add" method, I need to select the row where the new item was added and segue to an edit screen.  Obviously, depending on the other dates of items in the table, it could be anywhere.

I want to select it like this, but I don't have the indexPath:

```
[self.eventListTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
```

How do I determine which row (indexPath) my new object was added at so that I can select it properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsController` have a method called: [`indexPathForObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchedResultsController/indexPathForObject%3a)

If you have inserted items during your change processing (the FRC delegate methods), select the most recent inserted item. you can determine the index path of the object using the method above.

Or, you could keep the inserted object from your last insert, and in the `didChangeContent` delegate method, select the inserted item and nullify the variable you kept (so further calles won't trigger the segue).

Comment: So, like this then?  Add the method in my AddItem method and assign it an ivar, then in the didChangeContent delegate method if the ivar exists use indexPathForObject to slect and process the row and nil the ivar.  If ivar was nil already (because change was from edit or delete) just do nothing.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: exactly! (beware insertions from other source like web sync etc)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find the entity in your `NSFetchedResultsController` to resolve its `indexPath`. However to do that, you need to wait for your `NSFetchedResultsController` to recognize the object.  You will probably need to wait for the delegate callback methods from the `NSFetchedResultsController` to fire and then use `-indexPathForObject:` to resolve it back to an `indexPath` and then select the row.

Visually it should work perfectly.  The row will appear and then get selected.

Comment: Which callback method?  didChangeContent?

Comment: You could definitely do it there after you release the `UITableVIew` to update.

Comment: If not didChangeContent, then what are the other options?

Comment: There is also `-controller: didChangeObject: atIndexPath: forChangeType: newIndexPath:` that fires for every new row being added and already has the `indexPath`. You could explore putting it there as well.

Comment: I just noticed `-controller: didChangeObject: atIndexPath: forChangeType: newIndexPath:` where I am already watching for 'NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert' and inserting the row into the table with `insertRowsAtIndexPath`.  At that point, I already have the indexPath to the object.  Can I just do this: `[self.eventListTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];` there?  (I can't test right now.)

Comment: I can't test your code either :)  Give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: Haha!  I sure will.  I've found in my short experience with iOS that there are a lot of places to put things that seem to work but aren't the best choices because of other ramifications.  Will test tonight!